# Keeping duplicate values and trying pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that has various repeating elements. Below is an example of the table.

```
id     code  date
314asre B1  20201010
343asr  B2  20200405
150ase  B1  20210615
314asre B1  20210506
343asr  B3  20220408
```

I want to create something like this:

| id | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 314asre | 20201010 | NULL | NULL |
| 343asr | NULL | 20200405 | NULL |
| 150ase | 20210615 | NULL | NULL |
| 314asre | 20210506 | NULL | NULL |
| 343asr | NULL | NULL | 20220408 |

I tried using pivot and pivot table, but I got an error saying duplicate values in the index for the pivot, and pivot_table removes the duplicate values completely. I want to keep the duplicate values as shown in the above table.
Any help will be appreciated.

Code I have tried:

```
df.pivot_table(index='id' , columns = 'code' , values= 'date')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make pivot table with random index and change index to id column as follows.

```
df['temp'] = range(len(df))

result = df.pivot_table(index= 'temp', columns = 'code' , values= 'date')
result.index = df['id']
result
```

the result is as follows.

```
code    B1  B2  B3
id          
314asre 20201010.0  NaN NaN
343asr  NaN 20200405.0  NaN
150ase  20210615.0  NaN NaN
314asre 20210506.0  NaN NaN
343asr  NaN NaN 20220408.0
```